# how to group by two fileds in datatable in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a sql statment I get the data from it to the datatable but what I need is filtering the data by dataview and create group y with sum the quantity for each group:

```
SELECT 
                    FatoraReso as xAcc,
                    AccName AS xAccName, 
                    FatoraDate AS xDate,
                    FatoraProduct as xProdID,
                    ProductName AS xProdName,
                    FatoraPurPrice as xPrice, 
                    sum(FatoraQuan) as xQuan, 
                    COUNT(FatoraID) AS xCarCount
                    from tblfatora
                    INNER JOIN tblaccounts ON tblaccounts.AccID = tblfatora.FatoraReso
                    INNER JOIN tblproducts ON tblproducts.ProductID = tblfatora.FatoraProduct
                    GROUP BY xAcc,xDate,xProdID,xPrice

                    UNION ALL 

                    SELECT 
                    FatoraCustomer as xAcc,
                    AccName AS xAccName, 
                    FatoraDate AS xDate,
                    FatoraProduct as xProdID,
                    ProductName AS xProdName,
                    FatoraSalePrice as xPrice,
                    sum(FatoraQuan) as xQuan, 
                    COUNT(FatoraID) AS xCarCount
                    from tblfatora
                    INNER JOIN tblaccounts ON tblaccounts.AccID = tblfatora.FatoraCustomer
                    INNER JOIN tblproducts ON tblproducts.ProductID = tblfatora.FatoraProduct
                    GROUP BY xAcc,xDate,xProdID,xPrice
                    ORDER BY xProdID,xPrice
```

I made a filter by the xAcc and xDate and then I didn't know how to apply group by with get the sum for each group.
I saw some solutions about using The LINQ but really I don't anything about LINQ.
so can help me please.
the final table that I want is:

```
+---------+--------+-------+-----------+
| xProdID | xPrice | xQuan | xCarCount |
+---------+--------+-------+-----------+
| 1       | 55     | 10    | 2         |
+---------+--------+-------+-----------+
| 1       | 60     | 15    | 1         |
+---------+--------+-------+-----------+
| 2       | 150    | 12    | 3         |
+---------+--------+-------+-----------+
| 2       | 155    | 11    | 2         |
+---------+--------+-------+-----------+
```

tblfatora:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblfatora` (
`FatoraID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`FatoraRef` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`FatoraCode` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`FatoraDate` date NOT NULL,
`FatoraProduct` int(11) NOT NULL,
`FatoraQuan` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`FatoraReso` int(11) NOT NULL,
`FatoraPurPrice` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`FatoraPurTotal` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`FatoraCustomer` int(11) NOT NULL,
`FatoraSalePrice` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`FatoraDis` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`FatoraPlus` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`FatoraSaleTotal` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`FatoraDriverPayStatus` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`FatoraDriver` int(11) NOT NULL,
`FatoraCarNo` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`FatoraDriverCost` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`FatoraDriverCostTotal1` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`FatoraDriverCostTotal2` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`FatoraDriverPrice` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`FatoraDetails1` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`FatoraDetails2` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`FatoraDetails3` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`FatoraPalletQuan` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`FatoraPalletPrice` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

tblFatoraData:

```
INSERT INTO `tblfatora` (`FatoraID`, `FatoraRef`, `FatoraCode`, `FatoraDate`, 
`FatoraProduct`, `FatoraQuan`, `FatoraReso`, `FatoraPurPrice`, 
`FatoraPurTotal`, `FatoraCustomer`, `FatoraSalePrice`, `FatoraDis`, 
`FatoraPlus`, `FatoraSaleTotal`, `FatoraDriverPayStatus`, `FatoraDriver`, 
`FatoraCarNo`, `FatoraDriverCost`, `FatoraDriverCostTotal1`, 
`FatoraDriverCostTotal2`, `Fato`raDriverPrice`, `FatoraDetails1`, 
`FatoraDetails2`, `FatoraDetails3`, `FatoraPalletQuan`, `FatoraPalletPrice`) 
VALUES
(1, 202010180304112, '', '2020-10-01', 41, 31, 112, 71, 2201, 93, 71, 0, 0, 
2201, 'Paid', 128, '135538', 0, 0, 0, 1, '', '', '', 0, 0),
(2, 202010180720343, '', '2020-10-01', 43, 40, 112, 61, 2440, 83, 68000, 0, 
0, 2720000, 'Paid', 129, '', 0, 0, 0, 1, '', '', '', 0, 0),
(3, 202010180807273, '', '2020-10-01', 43, 34, 112, 61, 2074, 341, 72000, 0, 
0, 2448000, 'Paid', 130, '8142', 0, 0, 0, 1, '', '', '', 0, 0),
(4, 202010180819273, '', '2020-10-01', 50, 40, 114, 70, 2800, 76, 70, 0, 0, 
2800, 'Paid', 131, '', 0, 0, 0, 1250, '', '', '', 0, 0),
(5, 202010180821373, '', '2020-10-01', 55, 39.22, 114, 66, 2588.52, 55, 66, 
0, 0, 2588.52, 'Paid', 132, '', 0, 0, 0, 1250, '', '', '', 0, 0),
(6, 202010180823183, '', '2020-10-01', 50, 38, 114, 70, 2660, 360, 70, 0, 0, 
2660, 'Paid', 133, '', 0, 0, 0, 1, '', '', '', 0, 0),
(7, 202010180825173, '', '2020-10-01', 50, 39, 114, 70, 2730, 67, 64, 0, 14, 
2510, 'Paid', 134, '', 0, 0, 0, 1250, '', '', '', 0, 0),
(8, 202010180832333, '', '2020-10-02', 48, 31, 113, 63, 1953, 64, 56, 0, 0, 
1736, 'Paid', 135, '', 0, 0, 0, 1240, '', '', '', 0, 0),
(9, 202010180833593, '', '2020-10-01', 48, 35, 113, 63, 2205, 82, 63, 0, 0, 
 2205, 
'Paid', 136, '', 0, 0, 0, 1, '', '1', '', 0, 0),
(10, 202010180838003, '', '2020-10-01', 35, 35.46, 115, 57, 2021.22, 53, 56, 
0, 0, 1985.76, 'Paid', 137, '135280', 0, 0, 0, 1240, '', '', '', 0, 0),
(11, 202010180841213, '', '2020-10-02', 43, 33, 112, 61, 2013, 79, 58, 0, 0, 
1914, 'Paid', 138, '', 0, 0, 0, 1240, '', '', '', 0, 0),
(12, 202010180843373, '', '2020-10-02', 43, 39, 112, 61, 2379, 84, 70000, 0, 
 0, 2730000, 'Paid', 139, '10978', 0, 0, 0, 1, '', '', '', 0, 0),
(13, 202010180846253, '', '2020-10-02', 43, 39, 112, 61, 2379, 225, 56, 0, 0, 
2184, 'Paid', 140, '9705', 0, 0, 0, 1240, '', '', '', 0, 0),
(14, 202010180847593, '', '2020-10-02', 43, 40, 112, 61, 2440, 344, 61, 0, 0, 
2440, 'Paid', 141, '97464', 0, 0, 0, 1, '', '', '', 0, 0),
(15, 202010180849563, '', '2020-10-02', 43, 36, 112, 61, 2196, 73, 57, 0, 0, 
2052, 'Paid', 142, '', 0, 0, 0, 1240, '', '', '', 0, 0),
(16, 202010180852113, '', '2020-10-02', 43, 39, 112, 61, 2379, 357, 61, 0, 0, 
2379, 'Paid', 143, '151957', 0, 0, 0, 1, '', '', '', 0, 0)
```

Comment: if you don't want to use Linq, the you can always loop through all rows and do it manually. I am nt clear what group by and which sum you mean. i would take the hole select of your make parenthesis around it and use this in the from clause.

Comment: @nbk no problem with linq but I need the code that can help me, I want to make group by xprodid and xprice and getting the sum of xquan,xcarcount

Comment: @nbk I added in the post a sample about the final table that I need

Comment: @nbk please see the last comment in your answer

Comment: i have read your comment and in my answer i wrote why it will not be feasible. Second i don't like when i get my accepted answer remove or not get an upvote for all my effort.

Comment: @nbk dear, there is a misunderstanding, I don't mean that your effort not efficient but I meant not giving the mark for not answered question, your effort very great I'm serious :), now please tell me how I can solve this problem.

Comment: i expplained it very clearly you need to exclude all ros that have not the right dates, that can only made before the outer Group by, so see my answer again and do or try another approach

Comment: @nbk maybe I don't understand you well could you please give me a clear code, I tried but without correct results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use every Query as basis (subquery) too  do more calculations

```
SELECT
    xProdID,
    xPrice,
    xProdName,
    SUM(xQuan) AS xQuan,
    SUM(xCarCount) AS xCarCount
FROM (SELECT 
    FatoraReso AS xAcc,
    AccName AS xAccName,
    FatoraDate AS xDate,
    FatoraProduct AS xProdID,
    ProductName AS xProdName,
    FatoraPurPrice AS xPrice,
    SUM(FatoraQuan) AS xQuan,
    COUNT(FatoraID) AS xCarCount
FROM
    tblfatora
        INNER JOIN
    tblaccounts ON tblaccounts.AccID = tblfatora.FatoraReso
        INNER JOIN
    tblproducts ON tblproducts.ProductID = tblfatora.FatoraProduct
GROUP BY xAcc , xDate , xProdID , xPrice 
UNION ALL SELECT 
    FatoraCustomer AS xAcc,
    AccName AS xAccName,
    FatoraDate AS xDate,
    FatoraProduct AS xProdID,
    ProductName AS xProdName,
    FatoraSalePrice AS xPrice,
    SUM(FatoraQuan) AS xQuan,
    COUNT(FatoraID) AS xCarCount
FROM
    tblfatora
        INNER JOIN
    tblaccounts ON tblaccounts.AccID = tblfatora.FatoraCustomer
        INNER JOIN
    tblproducts ON tblproducts.ProductID = tblfatora.FatoraProduct
GROUP BY xAcc , xDate , xProdID , xPrice) t1
GROUP BY 
    xProdID , xPrice
ORDER BY xProdID , xPrice
```

As i wrote in my comment.

''Isee two possibility to get only the dates for one or more date.

The selection depends whetger you have a fast connection and a fast server.

**Solution 1;:**

You get all data into a table and have a dataview t filter your wanted dates.

then have a Sub which sums up the data according to xProdID , xPrice.

That is suitable if you a slow connection or a slow database server, so that the computer does it all on client side.

**Solution 2**

You send to the server a new SELECT as posted abouve only you add a where clause which only selects the appropriate dates before the final GROUP BY and SUM.

this works just fine, when all is quite fast.

The aggregation functions lose data, because it has only the max date, this may be enugh, but i don#t believe that it will suffice

Comment: it's not efficient, the SQL statement is good but I filter the data that is inside the Datatable by the user choice, filter according to (xDate and xAcc),  the missed thing that I need is getting the sum of quantity and sum of xcarcount with every product and price changning.

Comment: i can' follow you it should provide that, remove the columns from the GROUP By that you don't need. if you provide data, i can do it.

Comment: so as you can sse in the changed answer, it gives back what you postet

Comment: I added some data with the structure

Comment: pk that is a good start you need also to include the other tables, so that i can run the query. also can you add the result of the current query.

Comment: i started a fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=65b295ae32f698092e1c079b4169b969

Comment: the related tables don't matter, I just need to apply on this table please because the other tables are for getting some more information that not related with tblfatora

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8a309d0f792b109cea0a802676f63706

Comment: look i can't tes the query and you don't show me the result from my query , ican't can' help you so

Comment: that look like you wanted

Comment: no, your query is good I just removed the related tables and fields, and it's working but the problem is how I can filter the result by the date?

Comment: I assume that this data in the datatable and I will use data view to filter it by the date, how?

Comment: please, it's just one step as I think, I'm still trying to find a solution but I need help too

Comment: Add the date rto your result set, choose which you want MIN MAX , the problem with Grouping is that such deatils get lost, as you have to choose which date you want to represent. MIN MAX AVG. Otherwise you can't sort or filter, what you can do,. **don't** use dataview for that, instead grab the data filtered new from the server, computer and databses are fast enough for that and you can also add a range of dates, or a selection, everything you want frorm datepicker, i don't see another way

Comment: please see the link, it gives me the result collected, what I need is getting the results for every product and price for a specific account,  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b46512d451f628ec3ef16b5989bd05ac